# Firebase Firestore Reading Cost

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase firestore. It performs more than 100 reading operations in a single screen reading. This is too much in terms of cost. how can i improve this?

Example codes;

```
_categories.bindStream(
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(_categoryCollection)
      .snapshots()
      .map((event) {
    List<Category> _categories = [];
    event.docs.forEach((element) {
      _categories.add(Category.fromMap(element.data()));
    });
    return _categories.reversed.toList();
  }),
);

_subCategories.bindStream(
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(_subCategoryCollection)
      .where(
        "popular",
        isEqualTo: true,
      )
      .limit(6)
      .snapshots()
      .map((event) {
    List<SubCategory> _subcategories = [];
    event.docs.forEach((element) {
      _subcategories.add(SubCategory.fromMap(element.data()));
    });
    return _subcategories.reversed.toList();
  }),
);
```

Comment: Could you provide more context so we can see what is supposed to be improved?

Comment: Keep in mind: if you have the Firebase console open on the Firestore tab, you are also charged for the reads that screen performs. Would that explain what you're seeing?

Comment: I'm not sure but my console screen is on. only I'm looking to usage screen

Comment: the process of opening the application;
https://prntscr.com/1etgngf

Comment: how can i save money?

Comment: You should include the rest of the screen code.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele I don't understand you, but all working great. the reading cost is just too high.

Comment: What I mean is you should include the rest of the code so we can see how the streams are used. There might be other reasons contributing to the increased reads.